# Move routine to separate file

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I currently have a single assembly file, assembled with `nasm main.asm -f bin -o main.bin` and booted with VMware. I've also written some very basic string handling, which works fine, but I'd like to move it in a separate file.

```
mov si, message
call io.write

message db "Hello World\r\n===================\0"

io.write:
    [...]
```

So I put `io.write` in a second file, but I don't know what to do next. From what I gathered I need to put `global io.write` in the second file, and `extern io.write` in the first file. I could be completely wrong too. I also think I need to use a linker to achieve this, but I'm having trouble to understand how they work.

I've searched around but likely I'm not using the correct search terms. Any pointers are appreciated. I'd like to keep things simple and not use a makefile just yet, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think you'll have much luck with linking 16-bit code together, since it uses a segmented memory model. One alternative is to include all of your other `.asm` files in one "master" `.asm` file, and just assemble that "master" file.

Comment: I've been reading further and I was beginning to suspect as such. `%include` works fine, thanks.